# Hackney Fails to Make Request to Server

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am using the Phoenix Framework to run the following to connect to https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/videos/top. It has worked in the past, and not sure what caused this case to happen. Stopping and restarting iex doesn't seem to fix it. Running Elixir 1.0.5, Phoenix 0.14.0, Erlang OTP 18

```
iex(2)> "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/videos/top" |> 
...(2)> HTTPoison.get!()
** (exit) exited in: :gen_server.call(:hackney_manager, {:new_request, #PID<0.334.0>, #Reference<0.0.2.365>, {:client, :undefined, :hackney_dummy_metrics, :hackney_ssl_transport, 'api.twitch.tv', 443, "api.twitch.tv", [connect_timeout: 5000, recv_timeout: :infinity], nil, nil, nil, true, :hackney_pool, :infinity, false, 5, false, 0, nil, nil, nil, :undefined, :start, nil, :normal, false, false, false, nil, :waiting, nil, 4096, "", [], :undefined, nil, nil, nil, nil, :undefined, nil}}, :infinity)
    ** (EXIT) no process
    (stdlib) gen_server.erl:212: :gen_server.call/3
             src/hackney_client/hackney_manager.erl:65: :hackney_manager.init_request/1
             src/hackney_client/hackney_manager.erl:55: :hackney_manager.new_request/1
             src/hackney_connect/hackney_connect.erl:181: :hackney_connect.socket_from_pool/4
             src/hackney_connect/hackney_connect.erl:41: :hackney_connect.connect/5 
             src/hackney_client/hackney.erl:317: :hackney.request/5
             lib/httpoison.ex:60: HTTPoison.request/5
             lib/httpoison.ex:60: HTTPoison.request!/5
```

Comment: Did you start `HTTPoison` using `HTTPoison.start/0` in the shell?

Comment: Yes, this was the issue.

Comment: Don't start in the shell though if it is part of your app. Instead add HTTPoison to the list of applications in your mix.exs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you sure you've added `:httpoison` in the applications list in your `mix.exs`? I had the same problem, I kept banging my head on the wall for hours because of this:

```
def application do
  [mod: {MyAwesomeApp, []},
   applications: [:phoenix, :phoenix_html, :cowboy, :logger,
                  :phoenix_ecto, :postgrex, :httpoison]]
end
```

*Source: [HTTPoison#Installation](https://github.com/edgurgel/httpoison#installation)*

Comment: Note: You only need to explicitly add `:httpoison` to your applications list if you're running on something lower than Elixir 1.3.